# How to add hline and column sum to bottom of table using a src block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to (non-interactively) add (one hline and) a last line to a table in which the last column is summed.

Like so:

```
#+name: mytable
| p | q |
|---+---|
| a | 5 | 
| b | 2 |


#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var table=mytable
  (append table ?)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| p | q |
|---+---|
| a | 5 | 
| b | 2 |
|---+---|
|   | 7 |
```

I suspect `org-table-sum` can help, but I am unsure how.

Comment: and you don't want to use `#+tblflm: @3$2 = vsum (@I..II)` is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for your question! You may want to update the title of your question to clarify what is required.  Perhaps something like, `How to add hline and column sum to bottom of table using a src block?`. This change will help your question standout against the common *vsum is the answer* questions.

Comment: That is correct, @manandearth. I want to be able to do it non-interactively (as part of a babel block's :post function, to be exact).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
#+name: mytable
| p | q |
|---+---|
| a | 5 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |


#+begin_src emacs-lisp :var table=mytable :colnames yes 
  (let* ((total (apply '+ (mapcar 'car (mapcar 'cdr table))))  )
    (append table `(hline ("" ,total))))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| p |  q |
|---+----|
| a |  5 |
| b |  2 |
| c |  3 |
|---+----|
|   | 10 |
```

> **Tip:** To keep column names add `:colnames yes` to code block headers.

---

> **This code was tested using:**
>   emacs version: GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-cygwin, GTK+ Version 3.22.10)
>   Org mode version: 9.1.2

Comment: Great! This eats a potential existing header and its hline, though (which I did not add to my example table in the question). Not sure where in your code the `car` and `hline` get lost as all you seem to be doing is appending something.

Comment: I’ll take a look and see if I can fix that.

Comment: @Werner - I added `:colnames yes` to the headers of the code block which fixed the issue. Hope that helped! Thanks for asking your question!

Comment: For posterity (and the general robustness of your answer) it might be useful to ensure that the last column is added (as this strikes me as far more common), instead of the second. Would you agree?

Comment: @Werner - Good point! Thanks for the recommendation! I'm still learning elisp and several other lispy languages. I've read about a `last` function(?)/macro(?) but I can't remember which language. I'll read up, do some tests. and make the update to the answer.